# Can findall or finditer be used in this python ElementTree example?

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I want to process the following xml using ElementTree in python.
I need to find all Instance names when the UserValue title is THIRD and its value is not blank.  So in this example the result would be marble and mouse.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
    <Instance id="61" name="atom">
        <UserData id="30">
            <UserValue value="" title="FIRST"></UserValue>
            <UserValue value="" title="SECOND"></UserValue>
            <UserValue value="" title="THIRD"></UserValue>
            <UserValue value="watch" title="FOURTH"></UserValue>
        </UserData>
    </Instance>
    <Instance id="64" name="marble" ref="33">
        <UserData id="34">
            <UserValue value="" title="FIRST"></UserValue>
            <UserValue value="stuff" title="SECOND"></UserValue>
            <UserValue value="airplane" title="THIRD"></UserValue>
            <UserValue value="" title="FOURTH"></UserValue>
        </UserData>
    </Instance>
    <Instance id="65" name="rock">
        <UserData id="36">
            <UserValue value="" title="FIRST"></UserValue>
            <UserValue value="" title="SECOND"></UserValue>
            <UserValue value="" title="THIRD"></UserValue>
            <UserValue value="" title="FOURTH"></UserValue>
        </UserData>     
    </Instance>
    <Instance id="66" name="mouse">
        <UserData id="38">
            <UserValue value="" title="FIRST"></UserValue>
            <UserValue value="" title="SECOND"></UserValue>
            <UserValue value="rocket" title="THIRD"></UserValue>
            <UserValue value="" title="FOURTH"></UserValue>
        </UserData>     
    </Instance>
</Data>
```

This is the python code that I came up with.  It works fine and returns marble and mouse.
Is there is a way to use findall or finditer to do the same thing?

ANOTHER concern is that ElementTree appears to load the entire xml into memory to process and that may be a problem for my real xml which is nearly 300MB.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as xml

tree = xml.parse("example.xml")

for node in tree.iter('Instance'):

    name = node.get('name')

    for col in node.iter('UserValue'):
        title = col.attrib.get('title')
        value = col.attrib.get('value')

        if (title == "THIRD" and value != ""):
            print "     name =", name
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend you to use [lxml](http://lxml.de/). You can use xpath expression with lxml.

```py
import lxml.etree

root = lxml.etree.parse("example.xml")
for instance in root.xpath('//Instance[descendant::UserValue[@title = "THIRD"][@value != ""]]'):
    print instance.get('name')
```

If above code takes too much memory try following code:

```py
import lxml.etree

class InstanceNamePrinter(object):
    def start(self, tag, attrib):
        if tag == 'Instance':
            self.name = attrib['name']
        elif tag == 'UserValue':
            if attrib['title'] == 'THIRD' and attrib['value'] != '':
                print self.name
    def close(self):
        pass

with open('example.xml') as xml:
    parser = lxml.etree.XMLParser(target=InstanceNamePrinter())
    lxml.etree.parse(xml, parser)
```

Comment: Thanks falstru.. lxml was 10 times faster than elementtree in my case

Comment: @panofish, Did you try the second version in my answer?

Comment: yes... it worked as well, but the performance improvement was only slightly faster.  My code took 100 seconds, your first technique took 11 seconds and the second technique took 9 seconds.  But I guess the advantage is in how it uses much less memory

Comment: @panofish, Did you check memory usage? The second version will consume less memory.

Comment: Thanks falsetru.  Memory usage wasn't a problem yet, but it could be in the future, so I appreciate the extra work!